# Complex analysis - particles moving in time (why scaled unit circle particle, i.e. $e^{at}e^{ibt}$ starts path from $0$)

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry for bomabrding you with yet another visual complex analysis book question.

I am looking at the following depiction:

[image]

It shows how the "particle" spirals away from the center if we scale the particle that moves around in loops in the unit circle ($e^{ibt}$). i.e. we scale the particle with $e^{at}$, such that as time goes by, this scaling factor increases exponentially... obviously. So the location of the scaled particle at time $t$ would be:

$$Z(t) = e^{at} e^{ibt}$$

I am trying to understand why the particle that spirals away starts its path from the origin (i.e. zero), whereas the particle that travels in loops in unit circle starts its path at 1 (dashed lined).

I initially thought, and it must be true, that it is due to the fact that we scale the particle, i.e. we multiply the unit circle particle with $e^{at}$. However, if we consider what happens at time $t=0$, then $Z(0)=e^{a \cdot 0}e^{ib \cdot 0} = e^0 e^0 = 1$, so algebraically at time $0$ the spiralling particle should be at $1$. And I believe that is true from the depiction, since for the unit circle particle we start at $1$ and so is the case for the spiraling particle. But then the question is, what is that spiraling section that originates from the zero? We can't have $t < 0$...

I am confused

EDIT:

This is probably a better figure:

[image]

Comment: More context would be helpful, but time is probably starting from $-\infty$.

Comment: Sorry. yes, the page is $20$: https://math.uc.edu/~herron/complex_analysis/Texts/VisualComplexAnalysis-Needham.pdf

Comment: I think it's safe to say they are plotting the curve for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. "Negative time" is really not that crazy of a notion - if we consider $t=0$ to be "right now," then negative time just looks back into the past. The description of the particle's motion is just to assist one in understanding the mathematics.

Comment: Oh yes, if we did have negative time then that $e^{at} < 1$ and so it dampens the second one, which actually is also less than one. I see now.. Thanks